# CMake - Pass environment variable without expanding

Tags: cmake

In CMake I'm doing something like this:

```
LINK_DIRECTORIES( $ENV{VARNAME}/lib )
```

However, that will expand the environment variable so that the generated visual studio project will have a hard coded path, e.g:

```
C:/PathToWhereVarNamePointed/lib
```

Is there a way to make the above call so that visual studio will end up the below instead?

```
$(VARNAME)/lib
```

Comment: Have you tried `%VARNAME%`? This is how environment variables are expanded in Windows. If by "environment variable" you mean system's variable like here: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html `${}` syntax is for expanding CMake local/cache variables

Comment: You can use `\${VARNAME}` to so that it is not expanded as a variable.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say $ENV{VARNAME}, question has been updated.

Comment: The main problem I'm having is that if I escape the environment variables, e.g. \$\(VARNAME\)/lib, then it will treat it as a relative path an prepend my cmake directory to it.  @metal's answer will fix that for `LINK_DIRECTORIES`, but I'm not sure how to fix it for `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`

Comment: @pauld `target_link_directories`, `target_link_options` can accept linker options.  Directly setting `LINK_DIRECTORIES` property may bypass CMP0015 processing.  But it doesn't seem usual to adjust the linker search path as it seems more common to provide the entire path to the library to be linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [CMake 2.8.1 changed how this value is interpreted](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/policy/CMP0015.html?highlight=cmp0015) (relative vs. absolute), in addition to escaping the dollar and the parens, you need to set the old policy:

```
CMAKE_POLICY( SET CMP0015 OLD )
LINK_DIRECTORIES( 
    \$\(VARNAME\)/lib
)
CMAKE_POLICY( SET CMP0015 NEW )
```

Then it shows up like:
[image]
The CMake docs say that `LINK_DIRECTORIES` is "[rarely necessary](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html)". Are you sure this is the right way to do it?